# How to use the default browser scrollbar when `scrollOverflow:true` on fullPage.js?

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

Is there a way to use the browser native scrollbar when `scrollOverflow:true` instead of the additional `scrolloverflow.js` file?

I want to use fullPage.js only on the home page of a WP site and I want all pages to have the default scrollbar.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible at the moment. At least, it's not something provided by fullPage.js out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by setting `scrollOverflow:false` (default value) and defining an extra container inside the desired fullpage section like this:

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="inner-section">...</div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inner-section {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This seems to work fine on desktop screens, but on mobile screens, there are problems with swiping.